# print thailand characters on bluetooth printer android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, localization

I need to print Thailand characters through Bluetooth printer. 
If i print the data to android console it's displays properly in thai language.

But the same data when sent to bluetooth printer, it prints some junk value.

I have tried

```
encoding to Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("วันที่").array();

String str = "วันที่".getbytes(Charset.forName("TS-620")).
```

but nothing seems to be working fine. Can some 1 guide me on this.

Comment: Did you solve this?